# Delete first space (to_char) SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, to-char

I write a select:

```
select orderid, 
       unitprice*(1-discount)*quantity as "a", 
       to_char(unitprice*(1-discount)*quantity, '99999D99') as "SUM"
from OrderDetails
where unitprice*(1-discount)*quantity > 5000
```

Result is:
[image]

How delete only first space?

Mask for char (only 8 symbols):

 [number/space][number/space][number/space][number/space][number].[number][number] 

If use 'FM', when result:
[image]

But, i need:
[image]

Comment: Use the "fill mode": http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF30003

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leading space is for the sign. If you are sure you use only positive numbers you can remove the sign token with a substring.
If you have a sign you can put it at the end if you want like this:

```
99999D00S
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want the format mask of your `to_char` to be `fm9999D00`, i.e.

```
to_char(unitprice*(1-discount)*quantity, 'fm99999D00') as "SUM"
```